# How to change the camera input from column to row wise in streamlit

Tags: python, streamlit

I have an app which get the input as web image and convert into cartoonic image but it displays the  camera input and output in column wise instead of that i need side by side(row wise)

Don't know whether we can reduce the width of the camera.input??

Any idea would be appreciated!

```
import cv2
import streamlit as st
import numpy as np 
from PIL import Image
import base64
from torch import square

def cartoonization (img):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)            
    gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray, 7) 
    edges = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 7, 7)
    blurred = cv2.bilateralFilter(img, d=7, sigmaColor=200,sigmaSpace=200)
    cartoon = cv2.bitwise_and(blurred, blurred, mask=edges) 
    return cartoon

###############################################################################
    

file_image = st.camera_input(label = "Take a pic of you to be sketched out")

if file_image:
    input_img = Image.open(file_image)
    final_sketch = cartoonization(np.array(input_img))
    st.write("**Output Pencil Sketch**")
    one = st.columns(1)
    st.image(final_sketch, use_column_width=True)
    #with one:
        # st.write("**Input Photo**")
        #st.image(input_img, use_column_width=True)
    #with one:
        # st.write("**Output Pencil Sketch**")
        # st.image(final_sketch, use_column_width=True) 

else:
     st.write("You haven't uploaded any image file")
```